# Curvature of Lie groups

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Can a Lie group be of negative sectional curvature? 
In fact every Lie group contains an entire curve which means that a Lie group does not admit a complete metric with negative sectional curvature

Comment: This question makes sense only if you say more precisely how you define a metric on the Lie group: what kind of metric, satisfying which conditions?

Comment: I'm talking about the Hermitian metric (defined by a positive (1,1)form )

Comment: I agree that this is still unclear — but would guess that Milnor’s “[Special Example 1.7](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0425012)” gives a positive ($=$ negatively curved...) answer to what is probably intended. Does it?

Comment: The problem for me is: how a complex Lie group on the one hand admits a Riemannian metric with negative sectional curvature and on the other hand it contains copies of \ C therefore it contains entire curves (image of \ C by holomorphic function ) and we know that the presence of an entire curve implies the inexistence of a metric with negative sectional curvature